# Maintaining two Git repos side by side

Tags: git, github, version-control

Let's say I've one Git repo named Patterns which is my main repo and usually me and my team push and update our code base here. Now I want to create a new repo named NewPatterns from this same repo (`git clone Patterns`) but it will be maintained separately and will have a separate remote Git repo for updates.

Now the second part here is that if there is any update on Patterns repo, I want to pull those changes to NewPatterns repo (resolve conflicts if there are any) and then push changes to NewPatterns remote.

I want to do some experimentation with my live project but don't want to touch or to branch the main repo. And if NewPatterns features are acceptable, I want to merge the NewPatterns in Patterns repo.

I've read somewhere that we can have two remote origin linked to the same local repo but don't know if that will serve my this purpose.

Comment: What you read is correct and will allow you to do what you explain, so you should follow wherever you initially read this. 'though I'm not quite sure from your description why you'd want a separate repository as opposed to additional branches in the original repository. That's *usually* how you do "independent development that will eventually be merged back in".

Comment: Also, from the Github side your second repository should be a fork of the first one, then you can even directly do a PR between the two via the Github UI.

Comment: thank you but fork option is grayed out because I'm the owner of main repo.

Comment: Yeah, probably because creating a fork doesn't make a lot of sense if you can just do stuff in the main repo. Can you explain a bit more why you don't want to work with branches? Because from everything you described, they match your use case perfectly, except that you say you don't want to use them.

Comment: As mentioned its same project with experimental features that may or may not make it to the production so priority of these features is low compared to the live features and bug fixes and if some bugs are reported on production, I'll have to either stash or commit any ongoing developments before switching to production branches for fixes. This kind of stashing is acceptable in production branches since you will be coming back to these as soon as you publish fixes but in low priority scenario, it can take sometime to get started again.

Comment: And I think doing these experimentation in separate project is flexible since you don't have to stash or commit any unwanted code. Finish what you are doing commit and if there is any update on production, pull from Patterns remote and you are good to go.

Comment: The "stashing" is simply a local thing, that's entirely independent of whether you use the same central repository or not. You can simply clone your main repository twice and leave one checked out on the development branch and the other on the main branch and get what you want (you can further optimize that by using one clone with two worktrees). There's absolutely no need to have two separate central repositories for what you describe.

Comment: Can you please write commands for better understanding. Because I want to do it proper way and my approach sure does seems a bit of hackish.

Comment: You already know all the commands! You already cloned your repo once to work on it locally. So simply do that again (to another directory) and you'll have two separate clones. Stay in the main branch in one, stay in the development branch in the other. Then each one can push to their respective branches without "polluting" the other and you never have to switch around and/or stash. You can ignore the "worktree" mention for now, but if you want to look into it google is your friend, it's well documented.

Comment: Haha yeah actually the "worktree" did got me. everything else was clear.